# Can't .find() tag after usage of .attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery with `node-horseman` to click on a page, and I'm basing myself on a `data-id` that this page has, passing to my application to look for the `li` tag with this attribute:

```
jQuery('#manage-alerts-div li').attr('data-id', this.feedID)
```

But I need to find another tag inside of this `li`, and by adding a `.find()` after this, just a blank link is returned, and I cannot see it's HTML content.

```
jQuery('#manage-alerts-div li').attr('data-id', this.feedID).find('.delete_button').click()
```

Comment: try this jQuery('#manage-alerts-div li[data-id=this.feedID]').find('.delete_button').click();

Comment: You're adding the attribute not selecting by it.

Comment: *ProTip* use *data* api to set `data-*`: $('#manage-alerts-div li').data('id', this.feedID). Also you telling that you can't get HTML content, but you call `.click()` that is triggering click event

Comment: Do ou want to select the `li` elements thathave the `data-id` equal to `this.feedID` or you want to add that attribute to them?

Comment: I want to select them.

Comment: I do not understand. If the `click` works, it affects all buttons on the screen, even though I could see the parent HTML of the button by specifying the `data-id `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work::

```
jQuery('#manage-alerts-div li[data-id="' + this.feedID + '"]').find('.delete_button').click();
```

Comment: @Rana IHi, it's returning `undefined` when I try to `.html()` it

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir The quotes aren't strictly necessary. It works fine without them.

Answer (score 2):

> **The jQuery method `end()` Description:** End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state.

You could use the jQuery method **[`end()`](https://api.jquery.com/end/)** like :

```
jQuery('#manage-alerts-div li').attr('data-id',  this.feedID).end().find('.delete_button').click();
______________________________________________________________^^^^^
```

If you want to search by `data-id` then you could use :

```
$('#manage-alerts-div li[data-id='+this.feedID+']').find('.delete_button').click();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.delete_button').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).closest('li')[0].outerHTML);
})

var feedId = 20; //Should be 'this.feedID' in your case 
$('#manage-alerts-div li[data-id='+feedId+']').find('.delete_button').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id='manage-alerts-div'>
  <li data-id='10'>Text 1 <button class='delete_button'>delete button 1</button></li>
  <li data-id='20'>Text 2 <button class='delete_button'>delete button 2</button></li>
  <li data-id='30'>Text 3 <button class='delete_button'>delete button 3</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Doesn't it throws away `$('#manage-alerts-div li')` after using `.end()`?

Comment: The suggestion did not work, unfortunately. It's actually clicking on all `.delete_button` on the page.

Comment: Ok @GabrielMFernandes which one you want to click? you're specifying no index

Comment: The `this.feedID` finds the parent `li` of the `.delete_button` class

Comment: I do not get it. It also returns `undefined`, if I `.html()` the button.

Comment: If you want to get the button HTML check my updated snippet using `outerHTML`.

Comment: All `undefined`. Will continue next day.

Comment: I do not understand. If the `click` works, it affects all buttons on the screen, even though I could see the parent HTML of the button by specifying the `data-id `